# Cannot access environment variables in the server/index.js in Nuxt.js

Tags: environment-variables, nuxt.js

I'm trying to add environment variables to the `nuxt.config.js` file in the `env` property to access the variables in `server/index.js` file but it gives `undefined`. According to the [env](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-env) documentation, the variables should work in both client and sever. Not sure if i'm missing something? Thanks in advance.

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    baseUrl: process.env.BASE_URL || 'http://localhost:3000'
  }
}
```

Comment: no, declaring env var in nuxt config means its accessible in nuxt code, not in external node code.

Comment: Oh okay! But then what does it mean in the documentation https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-env which says **Nuxt.js lets you create environment variables that will be shared for the client and server-side**. It mentions the server side.

Comment: You misunderstand what is server side. Server side isnt a backend. Its nuxt code that is executed on server side.

Comment: Got it and this makes things clear. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

All env variables in Nuxt.js must start with `NUXT_ENV`.
In vue.js it must start with 'VUE_APP'

Answer (score 1):

In your `.env` file rename variable like `VUE_APP_BASE_URL`, and use it with that name.

.env file just allow variables that starts with `VUE_APP`.

You can read more [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/787).

Comment: I think you misunderstood! It's not the issue with the `BASE_URL` variable itself but declared variables in env property of `nuxt.config.js` itself. The variable i declare should be accessible in client and server. Which if i understand should accessible in `server/index.js (node entry file)` but instead i get undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's quite a late answer but just came across the same issue and thought my findings might help to some future mate in trouble.

It was as simple as include the `require('dotenv').config()` before any `process.env.XXX` reference.

Note that you might have better solution if [using nuxt 2.13+.](https://nuxtjs.org/blog/moving-from-nuxtjs-dotenv-to-runtime-config)